# Does Lua have OR comparisons?

Tags: if-statement, lua, logic

I'm just starting out using Lua, and I was wondering (because I can't find it on the website) if Lua has a OR operator, like how in other languages there is ||:

```
if (condition == true || othercondition == false) {
 somecode.somefunction();
}
```

whereas in Lua, there is

```
if condition then
    x = 0
end
```

how would i write an IF block in Lua to use OR?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

With "or".

```
if condition or not othercondition then
    x = 0
end
```

As the Lua manual clearly states.

Comment: Lua does not have an operator `!`; it uses `~` instead.

Comment: Not `~` (which is used only in `~=`, i.e. "not equals"), but `not`. Fixed the example in answer.

Comment: Voops. Coding in one language, answering in another, inevitably leads to mistakes.

Comment: It should be noted that in Lua, an "or" expression does not necessarily return a boolean value. It returns the first argument (without even executing the second one) if its value is not false or nil.